# openwire vs amqp, Which would perform better

Tags: jms, rabbitmq, activemq-classic, amqp, spring-jms

We currently use JMS API with ActiveMQ broker, looking over to move to RabbitMQ.
Compared to openWire vs amqp which one would give best performance with java client-producer. I Couldn't find a comparison study on amqp(RabbitMQ) vs openwire (activeMQ) native protocol. I'm looking in terms of raw performance and ease of scalability.

We currently use Spring Integration for ActiveMQ, I would like to know if its a drastic change to move to RabbitMQ(AMQP) even with Spring Integration. Is there any bridge similar to what ActiveMQ uses to do JMS<->AMQP forwarding ?

Answer (score 6):

ActiveMQ also supports AMQP: http://activemq.apache.org/amqp.html

Both are binary protocols. Openwire is going to be more full-featured when using ActiveMQ.

For "raw performance" you'll have to nail down your use cases first. Chances are the protocol you choose (ampq vs openwire) is not going to make any difference from a "perfomance" standpoint.

Answer (score 2):

ActiveMQ now implements AMQP.

You can specify multiple communication protocols and let ActiveMQ auto detect determine which to implement: 
http://activemq.apache.org/auto.html