# ActiveMQ: Openwire vs AMQP vs Stomp

Tags: java, activemq-classic, amqp, stomp

ActiveMQ is a Message Broker that supports many different protocols such as Openwire, AMQP and Stomp. It is really confusing to know:

- what are the differences between using Openwire and AMQP as a base protocol to send and receive messages in the project?
- what are the merits and demerits of any of those protocols over each other?
- Is this possible to use them in a same machine simultaneously?
- Is there any possibility to send a message from the browser using Stomp and receive that message in the server using two other protocols?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For 1 and 2, maybe this page is helpful:

- [openwire vs amqp, Which would perform better](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19785221/openwire-vs-amqp-which-would-perform-better)

3. yes, a single ActiveMQ instance can provide all protocols at the same time
4. yes, see [AMQP & Openwire - Activemq broker and 2 different consumers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28799477/amqp-openwire-activemq-broker-and-2-different-consumers)